# Запрос на сайт через прокси C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, proxy

Моя задача такая. Я создаю программу для твича. Мне нужно организовать многопоточный запрос через прокси. Какими методами стоит воспользоваться?

Comment: Просмотры накручивать?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, твитч (также, как ютьюб и некотрые амазоновские сервисы) использует сложный и очень нетривиальный алгоритм детектирования ботов. Так что по простому накрутить - не получится. Ну, получится с каждого проксика по одному - два клика сделать, а потом - баста. Хотя, сама по себе задачка не очень сложная, я уже пытаюсь написать пример кода, обнаружил в процессе, правда, небольшой пробел в своих знаниях :-)

Comment: Создаете `HttpClient`, чтобы он закрывал сокет сразу после использования, вешаете на `HttpClientHandler` нужный `WebProxy`. Ну и вперед по базе проксей с ограничением на количество одновременных асинхронных запросов, скажем до 20, с помощью `SemaphoreSlim`. Получится то что вы хотите, но вот вероятность, что сработает с твичом, нулевая.

Comment: Смотрю непроста задачка то. Я так понял нужно копать глубже? Библиотеку Leaf.xNet вообще стоит рассматривать?

Comment: Вы хотя-бы один успешный запрос отправьте, чтобы он сработал, через прокси. А затем уж решайте вопрос как отправить миллион таких. У вас пока ни одного. Используемая библиотека не важна, делайте как вам удобно.